# create new associations in window7

Tags: windows-7, file-types

I want to add a file type extention called .phtml to the set association page. In this case I want eclipse to automatically open Zend .phtml files

Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: They unfortunately got rid of the file associations editor in the Control Panel in Vista, so the below solutions are your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Surely if you have an un-associated file, when you double-click it you will get the option as to what you want to open it with. After that, pick the program and then tick the box to "allways use this program".

Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe right click .phtml file-> properties->General-> Open with|change->Browse for eclipse executable and double click.